# Access: 'Aggregate' Type is no valid name

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have two different DELETE queries, but both raise the same error:

`Aggregate Type' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.`

My code looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM T_PROPOS WHERE T_PROPOS.ID NOT IN
(SELECT T_PROPOS.ID
FROM T_PROPOS INNER JOIN T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate ON 
(T_PROPOS.Projekt = T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate.[Projekt]) AND
(T_PROPOS.[PSP-Element] = T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate.[PSP-Element]) AND
(T_PROPOS.Typ = T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate.[Typ]) AND 
(T_PROPOS.Jahr = T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate.[Jahr]) AND 
(T_PROPOS.Wert = T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate.Wert) AND 
(T_PROPOS.Datum = T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate.MaxvonDatum));
```

and the other one like this:

```
DELETE 
FROM T_PROPOS
WHERE NOT
(
(([T_PROPOS].[Projekt])=[T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate].[Projekt]) And 
(([T_PROPOS].[PSP-Element])=[T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate].[PSP-Element]) And 
(([T_PROPOS].[Typ])=[T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate].[Typ]) And 
(([T_PROPOS].[Jahr])=[T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate].[Jahr]) And 
(([T_PROPOS].[Wert])=[T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate].[Wert]) And 
(([T_PROPOS].[Datum])=[T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate].[Datum])
);
```

T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate is a query and looks like this:

```
SELECT Max(T_PROPOS.Datum) AS MaxvonDatum, T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 1], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 2], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 3], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 4], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 5], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 6], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 7], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 8], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 9], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 10], T_PROPOS.Ressort, T_PROPOS.Status, T_PROPOS.Projekt, T_PROPOS.Programm, T_PROPOS.[Budget/plan 2016ff], T_PROPOS.Digitalisierung, T_PROPOS.[FI-Abteilung], T_PROPOS.nt5, T_PROPOS.nt6, T_PROPOS.x, T_PROPOS.xx, T_PROPOS.xxx, T_PROPOS.[PSP-Element], T_PROPOS.Beschreibung, T_PROPOS.[IS-Projektmanager], T_PROPOS.Start, T_PROPOS.Ende, T_PROPOS.Einheit, T_PROPOS.Typ, T_PROPOS.Jahr, T_PROPOS.Wert
FROM T_PROPOS
 GROUP BY T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 1], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 2], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 3], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 4], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 5], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 6], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 7], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 8], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 9], T_PROPOS.[Portfolio Level 10], T_PROPOS.Ressort, T_PROPOS.Status, T_PROPOS.Projekt, T_PROPOS.Programm, T_PROPOS.[Budget/plan 2016ff], T_PROPOS.Digitalisierung, T_PROPOS.[FI-Abteilung], T_PROPOS.nt5, T_PROPOS.nt6, T_PROPOS.x, T_PROPOS.xx, T_PROPOS.xxx, T_PROPOS.[PSP-Element], T_PROPOS.Beschreibung, T_PROPOS.[IS-Projektmanager], T_PROPOS.Start, T_PROPOS.Ende, T_PROPOS.Einheit, T_PROPOS.Typ, T_PROPOS.Jahr, T_PROPOS.Wert;
```

I am quite confused as I am not even using an Aggregate Function (well I do in the T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate query)? Or what does the error mean? Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are `T_PROPOS` and `T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate` tables or views?

Comment: T_PROPOS is a table and T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate is a query

Comment: Will SELECT query on each table/query work? Will SELECT with JOIN work? What is SQL of Duplikate?

Comment: Yes SELECT query work on theor own. I edited my question, you can see SQL auf Duplikate now.